# How to invoke servlet in JSP page

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm amateur in Spring Java EE. This's my beginning. Can anyone tell me: it is possible to get some data from servlet in JSP page without creating FORM and without refreshing page?

I'm using Spring Framework with Hibernate and JSP. After log in through Spring Security, there is load main page: index.jsp. On this page - I will show quick desktop for logged user with some information (name, surname, etc) getting from database using hibernate. As you can guess -  I wont reload/redirect this page, so using FORM clause is impossible.

Questions:
1. Can I invoke servlet from JSP page to get users data from database without reloading/redirect page? Just: simple invoking servlets function and fetching result of this function as hibernate objects. 
2. Is there any way to invoke Hibernate to fetch data directly in JSP page?

Or please tell me how to resolve this problem using simple and efficient technique.

Thanks for your help.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Sounds like Ajax may be your best bet.

Comment: Why do you forward to a JSP after successful login, instead of forwarding to the servlet?

Comment: Brilliant JB Nizet. Thank you!
But for the future: is any way to invoke servlets function from JSP? 
My content is huge (HTML consists whole page with menu, content and footer). This is no effective to paste big part of code in response.getWriter function. Maybe you can tell me what to do i this case?

Comment: Read about the MVC pattern, and learn how to use Spring MVC, since you're already using Spring. A servlet is a controller. It's called first, prepares all the data that needs to be displayed in the page, store these data in request attribute(s), and then forwards to a JSP, which gets the data from the request, and displays it.

Comment: Spring MVC works perfect! Exactly what I want. Thank you very much JB Nizet :)